# How to prove that the error is not my Java agent or how to debug it?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, javaagents

One of our clients have contact me complaining that he's getting the following JRE crash while using our Java Agent.

According to the error (below) the crash is on the native code since the problematic frame is categorized as 'C'.

I've did some googling and it seems like there are some open bugs which are quite similar around this issue in this while using java agents. See the following links:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094079

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8041920

The issue is that the customer is reluctant to upgrade the JDK since he mentions that he has other java agents which are running without any issue.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

For the completeness, please see the error that he had sent:

```
cat /opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/hs_err_pid6697.log | grep sealights
7fe19d9b5000-7fe19d9d7000 r--s 00401000 ca:01 3539943                    /opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/sealights/sl-test-listener.jar
jvm_args: -javaagent:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/hawtio/jolokia-jvm.jar=config=/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/conf/jolokia-agent.properties -javaagent:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/agent/newrelic.jar -DNEWS_product_HOME=/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name -Dsl.environmentName=Functional Tests DEV-INT -Dsl.customerId=myCustomer -Dsl.appName=ABB-product-name -Dsl.server=https://my-server.com -Dsl.includes=com.somecompany.* -javaagent:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/sealights/sl-test-listener.jar -Dlog.dir=/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/logs -Dlog.threshold=debug
java_class_path (initial): some-product-name.jar:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/hawtio/jolokia-jvm.jar:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/agent/newrelic.jar:/opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/sealights/sl-test-listener.jar

JVM crash message:

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000055, pid=6697, tid=140604865455872
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000055
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/somecompany/apps/some-product-platform/some-product-name/hs_err_pid6697.log
Compiled method (c1)  565518 13823       1       sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions::identity (2 bytes)
total in heap  [0x00007fe1a76857d0,0x00007fe1a7685a48] = 632
relocation     [0x00007fe1a76858f8,0x00007fe1a7685918] = 32
main code      [0x00007fe1a7685920,0x00007fe1a7685980] = 96
stub code      [0x00007fe1a7685980,0x00007fe1a7685a10] = 144
metadata       [0x00007fe1a7685a10,0x00007fe1a7685a18] = 8
scopes data    [0x00007fe1a7685a18,0x00007fe1a7685a20] = 8
scopes pcs     [0x00007fe1a7685a20,0x00007fe1a7685a40] = 32
dependencies   [0x00007fe1a7685a40,0x00007fe1a7685a48] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: When you run your agent on the same Java version, are you able to reproduce it?

Comment: No. I've tried to use the same java version and the same linux machine (they use an instance from Amazon so I've created a machine from the same image).

Comment: In addition, in one of the bugs they've mentioned that it reproduce 'sometimes'. Fun for me :)

Comment: Are you re(transforming) any JDK classes from your agent?

Comment: Yes. We are re-transforming the URL class. Do you think that's related? If so, how did you came to this conclusion?

Comment: Some classes are rather essential to the JVM and are treated differently. For example, if you change the behavior of `java.lang.Object` or `java.lang.String` too much, then you will typically observe very erratic behavior and crashes are not too uncommon. What are you changing in the `URL` class? My gutt feeling tells me that you break the class loading mechanism (the built-in class loaders prior to Java 9 are based on URL connections) by changing the way URL behaves. Typically, you suffer some form of circularity where your instrumentation triggers class loading.

Comment: Also, look at `sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions` where methods are bound to call sites at the `identity` call which can trigger class loading. This is another indicator. The reproduction probably depends on the class loading order which is why it is difficult to reproduce and only happens "sometimes". It literally depends on what buttons are pressed in the application in what order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123931/discussion-between-nadavy-and-rafael-winterhalter).

Answer (score 0):

After asking for further details in the chat discussion, I assume that this error is related to the use of the ASM `AdviceAdapter` in combination with other agents in the same application. If the other agent expected a specific structure of a class, using the adapter might reorder variable indices of the class in question what the other agent does not anticipate. As the VM skips the verification of built-in classes, this results in a hard crash.

The solution would be the change the instrumentation to not use the `AdviceAdapter`.